# iOS 5 page curl with custom View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5, storyboard

I am trying to use page curl to show a sub page using Xcode storyboards.  Everything is working when I have the sub page as `UIViewController`, but when I change it to a custom `UIViewController`, the sub page is black.  Happens both on device and simulator. 
iOS 5
Xcode Version 4.2

Anyone seen this before?

Edit: This is happening every time when using a custom `UIViewController`, no matter if I use push or model.  If I use a custom UITableViewController it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in my ViewController which starts the transition this method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"prepare segue modal.partial_curl");
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"sample"]){
    "setgoalviewcontrollerobjecthere" = [segue destinationViewController];
}
```

}

don't forget to import .h file, alloc and init. name segue identifier in storyboard file "sample", and pick style modal, transition partial curl. easiest way works every time. If you do it just programmatically you have to do a lot more -> google

domink